# Public votes and avoiding mutliple vote: using cookies or IP?

Tags: javascript, social-media-like

How do you handle public vote (anyone can "like or dislike" an article) and to restrict him to vote only one time?

Have I to use cookies? (with the problem that he can remove the cookie and vote x999 times) or I store his IP in database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution has three parts:

1. use a cookie to prevent double votes
2. store all vote events in the database (ip, user agent, poll/article id, vote)
3. implement an algorithm which will run every 24h to delete the double votes which escaped from #1. The algo will use data from #2

Using only the IP is not appropriate as it can leave tons of people out of the voting system.

Answer (score 1):

Use the IP.

While you may cause a bunch of people from only voting once from behind one IP, the alternative is trivial to bypass (don't store cookies).

Answer (score 0):

I'd say do both so that if there are people with dynamic IP they will have to change IP and delete cookies at the exact same time.

Comment: You can essentially remove a whole group of people who use proxies. They all come from the same ip. Or am I wrong?

Comment: Well that's the drawback of IP limitations.

Comment: @John, not if you use the combination of both IP/cookie to create a *user*.

Answer (score 0):

If the user authenticates, ie they vote as themselves, throw a record in the database saying the user has already voted. For anonymous voters you are limited to cookies, local storage, ect.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of cookies could use [evercookie](http://samy.pl/evercookie/), which is much harder (but still possible) to bypass.

> evercookie is a javascript API
>   available that produces extremely
>   persistent cookies in a browser. Its
>   goal is to identify a client even
>   after they've removed standard
>   cookies, Flash cookies (Local Shared
>   Objects or LSOs), and others.

Comment: I'd never use this in my website since I respect my visitors.

Comment: Me neither, but it is an option the OP could use.  Also, as awareness about evercookie spreads hopefully there will be more options for easily deleting them.

Comment: but big site like facebook doesnt care about your privacy